# When inserting into mysql table from delphi Firedac i need the new Autoincrement id

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have a table with an auto incremental ID.
Multiple users are going to insert into the table.
There are no identifiable fields I can use to find the record I just added and need the auto-id of the record. What is the easiest way to get the latest ID of the newly added record?

One idea is to generate a GUID in the app and add it to the record and use that to identify the newly added record, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: For MySQL after an `INSERT` you can do `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the first ID inserted by the statement. If you only inserted one record then it's that record's ID.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a trigger to record the last insert id as well as the database user doing the insert statement.Note: This does not distinguish the Application users, as it's possible that multiple application users use the same DB user account to do their jobs)

```
create table test (id int primary key auto_increment, content varchar(10));
create table record (id int,content varchar(10),`user` varchar(20));

delimiter //
create trigger record_insert_id after insert on test for each row
begin
if not exists (select 1 from record where `user`=user()) then
insert record values(new.id,new.content,user());
else
update record set id=new.id,content=new.content where `user`=user();
end if; 
end//
delimiter ;

-- have user1 insert:
insert test (content) values('aaa'),('bbb');

-- have user2 insert:
insert test (content) values('xxx'),('yyy');

-- have user3 insert:
insert test (content) values('abcxyz');

select * from record;

-- result set:
# id, content, user
2, bbb, user1@localhost
4, yyy, user2@localhost
5, abcxyz, user3@localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a valid solution but as you mentioned only for different DB users, at the moment the same DB user is being used.

Comment: For the same DB user, this solution will keep updating the last_inserted for the same user. Unfortunately it can distinguish the different APP users using the same DB account.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

to get the LAST ID of the last row that has been inserted or updated in a table.